# Pattern not matching all phrase in a text file

Tags: java, pattern-matching

My program is not displaying the desired matching results. My text file contains the following line:

1. Red Car
2. Blue or Red
3. Red
4. Car

So If I search for: “Red Car”. I only get “Red Car” as the only result, but what I want is to get the following results:

1. Red Car
2. Red
3. Red
4. Car

Because these strings are in the text file. The Blue or Red, the “or” is logical. So I want to match either of them and not both. What am I doing wrong?
 Any help is appreciated. My code is as follows:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        //String key;
        String strLine;
        try{
    // Open the file that is the first 
    // command line parameter   
    FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("C:\\textfile.txt");
    // Get the object of DataInputStream
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        Scanner input  = new Scanner (System.in);         
        System.out.print("Enter Your Search:  ");
        String key = input.nextLine();

        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {     
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(key); // regex pattern to search for
        Matcher m = p.matcher(strLine);  // src of text to search
        boolean b = false;
        while(b = m.find()) {  
        System.out.println( m.start() + " " + m.group()); // returns index and match
    // Print the content on the console
        }
        }
        //Close the input stream
     in.close();  
        }catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
       System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
   }
 }
```

Comment: And what Regex you passed as input?

Comment: That would be why you only got "Red Car" back

Comment: So you want the space character to be considered as an OR operator for search?

Comment: the text file contains "Red Car", "Red", "Red or Blue" and "Car". Why am I getting ony Red Car as the only result. if I take Red Car and match the fist string which is Red Car. that is a 100% match. If I compare it to the next string then that is a match for the word Red. I want to display all teh matches including half matches like "Red" or "Car"

Comment: Yes the string "Blue or Red" I want to display either Red or Blue, if both words exist in my text file I want to display them as well.

Comment: FYI, you don't need to use a DataInputStream there.  I see this error so often, there must be textbooks and/or tutorials out there telling you to do that, but they are wrong.  DataInputStream is designed to read certain, very specific kinds of binary data; you'll probably never need to use it.  You *definitely* shouldn't be using it to read plain text files.

Answer (score 1):

Try passing this Regex: -

```
"((?:Red)?\\s*(?:or)?\\s*(?:Car)?)"
```

This will match: -

`0 or 1` Red followed by `0 or more` space followed by `0 or 1` Car

`(?:...)` is non-capturing group

**NOTE: -** The above Regex won't match: - `Car Red`.

If your order can be reverse, then you can use: -

```
"((?:Red|Car)?\\s*(?:or)?\\s*(?:Red|Car)?)"
```

And take the complete match from `group(0)`.

E.g: -

```
String strLine = "Car or Red";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("((?:Red|Car)?\\s*(?:or)?\\s*(?:Red|Car)?)"); 
Matcher m = p.matcher(strLine);  // src of text to search

if (m.matches()) {  
    System.out.println(m.group()); // returns index and match
}
```

**OUTPUT**: -

```
Car or Red
```

---

Replace your `while(b = m.find())` with `if (m.matches())`, as you want to match complete string, and just once.

Comment: Did you try passing this regex from keyboard?

Comment: @SalimShari.. If you are passing your Regex from keyboard, then just use single-backslash for your space. Pass: - `((?:Red|Car)?\s*(?:or)?\s*(?:Red|Car)?)` as input.

Answer (score -1):

Your pattern should be `Red|Car`.

Comment: Still not. It is goind to match either `Red` or `Car`. But not both. Which is required. See my answer.

Comment: It will match the string. Your answer is too complicated.

Comment: Your pattern means `match either Red or Car`. Now it would work for `Red Car` in case you use `find`, but not in case you use `match`. I mean it won't be exact match.

Comment: And how come my answer seem complicated to you? That regex I consider as simple. Complicated is not appropriate for it.

Comment: oh don't be boring, you know what I mean.

Comment: Your Regex also matches with: - `Car asfs` if you are using `m.find()`. And if you are using `m.matches()`, it won't match `Red Car`. So, in any case, it won't work.

Comment: `Car asfs` is not specified in the question. Neither me nor you know if a match is desired. Boring.